# Getting larger thumbnails for album photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, photos

Is there a way to get **different sized photo thumbnails** when retrieving an **album's photos**?

[Example album photos from documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150146071791729/photos)

Right now, it looks like I get two sources for each image:

- 'picture' (thumnail): xxxx_s.jpg
- 'source' (original): xxxx_n.jpg

Is there was a parameter to pass to get medium or large versions of the thumbnail?

I tried using the **'type'** paramater *(like for profile pictures)*, but I always get back the **small** (**'_s.jg'**) version.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a comment here that says trying out type=album might work (http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6629188/facebook-graph-api-how-do-you-retrieve-the-different-size-photos-from-an-album#comment7829406_6629311). But the Graph API should be returning all sizes of the photo, why not choose one from that that matches your needs ?

Comment: I agree with Deepak. Why not rescale the large image within your application yourself to fit your needs?

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks for the input, guys! I now see the `images` array. It doesn't give a key like 's', 'm', 'l', but rather dimensions as keys.